useradd: group '' does not exist when using -g to define primary group upon user creation
I'm following the exploratory exercises from https://learning.lpi.org/en/learning-materials/010-160/5/5.2/5.2_01/ and according to them this should work

yet, when I try this on ubuntu 22.04 ,brand new install, I get this (WTF?)

adding a user to a group I know it can be done with usermod aG  and that's all fine, but why wouldn't this be possible when adding the user to a specific primary group upon creation, since according to man adduser that's an option with -g (--gid) ?
I found this answer sort of related to my question but it only says to use usermod and be done with it, here they also use usermod to change the primary group name.
I'm just wondering why would the command not work and why do I get that error, lastly, is there something to change so I don't get it?

You have a space between web_admin, and db_admin. The space makes the argument passed to the -G option web_admin,, which is a comma-separated list of two values: web_admin and "" (an empty string), hence the error

do I feel stupid.. damn it... a freaking hour searching for this. Thank you @kos

We've all been there. You're welcome
